How to implement Publisher Confirms in Node Js asynchronously
I have been trying to implement a data synchronizer among the services. I have set it up like any core db changes are sent to all other micro services by a fanout exchange. Now if any failures in synchronization both in transit or in client side needs to be addressed.
I have studied the examples from the rabbitmq documentation in java. But I can't find any implementation in Node js. There is a way to create the confirmChannel and waitForConfirms. But I need something like attaching listeners to the channel and do it asyncronusly like they did in the java example
